# Replace the first column in a file with another column in different file using shell

Tags: shell

I have two files file1 and file2

file1

```
Shyam=123=12.3.4.5=user@gmail.com
Shyam=123=12.2.5.4=user@gmail.com
Joshwa=234=14.3.4.67=user@gmail.com
Anil=879=15.3.4.98=user@gmail.com
Anil=765=15.4.5.65=user@gmail.com
```

.......

file2

```
Shyam=ShyamLal
Joshwa=JoshwaSam
Anil=AnilAcharya
```

....

"=" is mentioned as a seperator in file1 and file2.

I want to update names as given in file2. ie.,Shyam will be replaced with ShyamLal, Joshwa will be replaced with JoshwaSam and Anil will be replaced with AnilAcharya. I don't want to use if-else condition, because I have large number of datas.

My output should be like:

```
ShyamLal=123=12.3.4.5=user@gmail.com
ShyamLal=123=12.2.5.4=user@gmail.com
JoshwaSam=234=14.3.4.67=user@gmail.com
AnilAcharya=879=15.3.4.98=user@gmail.com
AnilAcharya=765=15.4.5.65=user@gmail.com.
```

I tried this. But don't know whether I am doing right

```
while IFS= read -r line

do
key=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $1}'` < file1.txt

value=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}' < file2.txt`

 cat file1.txt | sed 's/$key/$value/g'

done
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to SO. On Stack overflow we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: My answer is ready :) once you add your efforts to your question, will post it as an answer then too.

Comment: Hello RavinderSingh,
I tried this. But still Iam not getting the output what I need
while IFS= read -r line

do key=echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $1}' < file1.txt

value=echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}' < file2.txt

cat file1.txt | sed 's/$key/$value/g'

done

Comment: Thanks for letting know your efforts here. I have un-deleted my solution now, kindly do check and lemme know in its comments section.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="="
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in a){
  $1=a[$1]
}
1
' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '           ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{          ##Starting BEGIN section here.
  FS=OFS="="    ##Setting FS and OFS as = for all lines here.
}               ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN section of this program here.
FNR==NR{        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file file2 is being read.
  a[$1]=$2      ##Creating an array named a with index $1 with value of $2 of current line.
  next          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a){      ##Checking condition if $1 is present in array a this will be done when Input_file1 is being read.
  $1=a[$1]      ##Setting $1 to array a value with index $1 of current line.
}
1               ##1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
' file2 file1   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Hello Ravinder,
Thanks for your help. Can u pls explain me this code. Iam not understanding some steps. By the way your code is working

Comment: @AjinJoy, Sure lemme add detailed explanation and let you know then.

Comment: @AjinJoy, Hi, have added detailed explanation for my code, kindly take a look to it.

Comment: Hello RavinderSingh, Thank you so much for your detailed explanations. My doubts are cleared

Comment: Hello RavinderSingh, Can u suggest an answer for the same question without using array concept

Comment: @AjinJoy, to be honest, it will be very very complex to do in some other approach, so IMHO better you could go with this approach. In case you have any other question, you can open a new question but make sure you add your efforts else people will ask you to do so, cheers :)